# My cheese congealed and I don’t know why?

Tags: salad

I mixed up a salad in a glass container I added dressing and goat cheese crumbles and shook it up. The next day when I went to eat it all the cheese ended up in a big congealed lump in the bottom of the container.  Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Did you put it in a refrigerator ? If yes, the fat can congealed like if you put olive oil in the refrigerator it become solid.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment to ask a question yet, so I'll try to phrase it as an answer. IF you used a vinaigrette, it could be possible that the vinegar broke down the cheese and/or the oil congealed in the fridge, like someone else mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

I imagine the cheese just "melted" in the presence of all the liquid in the vegetable and dressing.

You should try not prepare you salad a day before; or at least do not shake all the ingredients until you are ready to eat so that the more fragile ingredients do not wilter in the contact of the dressing, or don't add the dressing at that time, have a small container that you can use for the dressing.

If you are short on time, just have all the separate ingredients in different containers and assemble in the morning (or as close as possible to when you will eat it).

For example, have a look at this:

https://hurrythefoodup.com/how-to-pack-a-salad-in-a-jar/

Comment: Sorry, I don't see an explanation here. I don't think that the salad was heated, so the cheese probably didn't melt literally. And using it figuratively doesn't answer the question "why", it simply another description for what the OP already described.

Comment: Agree with @rumtscho : The primary question was about cause, not prevention. Adding some form of „try a his instead“ is nice, but doesn’t answer the question. There’s also no indication that the asker has problems with leafy greens, other ingredients may not only stand up to dressing, but actually benefit from a certain soaking time.

Comment: that's why I quoted the "melted" word; I know , from the OP, it was not heated; maybe; I still think the why because the cheese was in contact with the dressing.

Comment: maybe dissolve would be a better word ?

Comment: 'Dissolve' would be wrong here, since when something dissolves, the result is a liquid, not lumps within a liquid. And the point is not just to find a correct word to name the process, but also to explain why it happened.